# Don't inject attribute with JQ if there was none

Tags: json, jq

```
cat "$FileName" | jq --sort-keys 'map({"author_id": .author.id,"author": .author.name, "badge": .author.badges[0].title, "message", "timestamp", "time_in_seconds", "time_text"})' > "$TargetName"
```

produces output with `"time_in_seconds": null` if there was no `"time_in_seconds"` in source JSON. How to eliminate this:

- for this very attribute?
- for all attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove one field if it is `null`, use `.time_in_seconds |= select(.)`.

To remove all fields that are `null`, use `.[] |= select(.)`.

Add this inside your `map` at the end, like so:

```
jq 'map({…} | .[] |= select(.))'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RgWNdsnRVk)

Note: This will also delete fields with value `false`. If you want to restrict to `null`, make `select(.)` more explicit and change it to `select(. != null)`.

Comment: Thank you. I tested both variants on the real system. Both are working as expected.

Comment: If `"$Filename"` contains `"time_in_seconds":null`, should it be kept ?

Comment: No. But what if yes?

Comment: @Paul Your question seems to suggest *yes*, it could be understood this way : if an attribute (like `time_in_seconds`) exists in *source JSON*, then it should be included in the output, indepently of its value (null or not).

Answer (score 0):

To remove all `null` values (or any arbitrary condition) in your input, you could make use of `recurse/0` (`..`) and `del/1`.

```
del(.. | select(. == null))
```

Comment: You could eliminate the `select` and simplify it to just `del(.. | nulls)`.

Comment: Yes, that would work too, but I wanted to emphasize that it can be any arbitrary condition for the values to delete.